# XCode Storyboard - how are sceneId's generated?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm reverse engineering XCode Storyboards and theyre easy to generate except I was wondering if anyone one know the method call/format/algorithm Apple use to generate **sceneId** for each storyboard scene.
In this example sceneId is **"dA0-dT-CWd"**

```
 <!--CLKSyncLogViewController-->
        <scene sceneID="dA0-dT-CWd">
```

Nearest I can think of is a short version of a guid you might use in windows? But not seen these short ids in mac/ios dev before?

any clues?